# localhost to different domain not passing credentials

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cross-domain

I have an ajax call that i use to call a web page and i wanted to get the result.  The issue with it, is that it doesnt seem to work, and at the moment returns a *jQuery parse Error*.

When i look in the debug console and click though, it will take me to the page i want, it just doesnt seem to do it via ajax and store the result/ call success.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url:  "mywebsite",
  data: {username: username, password:password},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/json",
  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(result, status, jqxhr){ alert("success"); },
  error: function(xhr, status, message){ alert(status + ": " + message); }
});
```

as you can see i have some credentials i want to add to it, and i was told to have it in data, instead of doing the ajax options for *username* and *password*.

Im not sure whats going on, and it seems like there is something wrong.  I was looking at 3 different approaches via stack overflow, but none seemed to give me the correct answer.

**Posted Data**

```
 Request URL:http://10.224.65.5/mas3/DataSources/inspecttech.inspecttech/Schema/Classes?callback=jQuery17202808878293726593_1373384418801&username=njtax.hinspecttech&password=4e1cb7494843c513ee913d122e30ef2fe27635e5f82f575c92d006691906bebbbdb1fe483cfc06b087f7c4070c2879bd3585234a3614a1f04fca8de64ad6bfaf&_=1373384423017
 Request Method:GET
 Status Code:200 OK
 Request Headersview source
```

**Request Headers**

```
 Accept:*/*
 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
 Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
 Authorization:Basic bmRvdG1vYnguaG1vYmlsZWRldmljZTpzdXBlclNlY3JldERldmljZVBhc3N3b3Jk
 Connection:keep-alive
 Host:10.224.65.5
 Referer:http://localhost:3033/BentleyFormIntegrationFrameset.aspx
 User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
```

**Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded**

```
 callback:jQuery17202808878293726593_1373384418801
 username:njtax.hinspecttech
 password:4e1cb7494843c513ee913d122e30ef2fe27635e5f82f575c92d006691906bebbbdb1fe483cfc06b087f7c4070c2879bd3585234a3614a1f04fca8de64ad6bfaf
 _:1373384423017
 Response Headersview source
```

**Response Headers**

```
 Cache-Control:no-cache
 Content-Language:en-US
 Content-Length:801
 Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
 Date:Tue, 09 Jul 2013 15:40:22 GMT
 Expires:-1
 Mas-License-Error-Id:NoClientLicense
 Mas-License-Error-Message:Client's license is invalid.
 Pragma:no-cache
 Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
 X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
 X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

**additional Information**

Preview (In Google Chrome) shows the returned object, but im not sure why it would fail.  It looks like it fetched everything correctly.

**Possible alternate Option Via ASP?**

```
HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + site +"/DataSources/inspecttech.inspecttech/Objects/DeviceDatabase/" +action) as HttpWebRequest;

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(bic_name + "x.h" + user.in_username, user.in_password);
request.Credentials = cred;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
string resp = "";
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    resp += reader.ReadLine();
```

Comment: have you defined `username` and `password` anywhere?

Comment: `contentType`, `xhrFields`, `crossDomain`,`type`, and `error` can be removed, they are irrelevant for jsonp requests. If it isn't working, go to your console and the network tag and inspect the request. Post the request *and* response headers in your question along with a sample of the `responseText`.

Comment: I thought hes getting a js error, hes not even getting to the post.

Comment: Let me post the data for it

Comment: jQuery Parseerror with a jsonp request generally means the request was successful, but did not include properly formatted JSONP (and you aren't using the most recent version of jQuery since in the most recent version, jsonp requests can't call the error callback.)

Comment: @KevinB Well, then what would you reccomend to resolve this?  I cant update jQuery because it is the current version the office uses (1.7.2).  I figure it needs to stay "jsonp" but i could prolly change one of the other parameters such that this is resolved and fires success, or should i just tie into the **complete** call instead of **success**

Comment: the jQuery version doesn't matter, I probably shouldn't have even mentioned it. The problem is with what is being returned from the remote server. Therefore, you'll have to have it fixed at the remote server, or change the way you are requesting it (such as using a server-side proxy)

Comment: One possible to use a hidden iframe to point to it, and then just scrape the contents of the iframe, or use load() on a hidden div?

Comment: *"Preview (In Google Chrome) shows the returned object, but im not sure why it would fail. It looks like it fetched everything correctly."* What does the *"returned object"* look like? i'm interested in the first 50 characters or so. It should be: `jQuery17202808878293726593_1373384418801(...jsonhere...)` If it doesn't look like that, then it isn't JSONP.

Comment: Nope, if it's cross-domain, you can't access the contents of the iframe.

Comment: Both preview and response look like plain JSON, no pre-pended jQuery17202808878293726593_1373384418801, just *["item1","item2","item3"]*

Comment: I guess, instead of me doing it with javascript, maybe i should just tie in the control to ASP backend, and use the backend as a proxy instead of doing it entirely in js?

Comment: @KevinB do you think that is a viable option?

Comment: @Fallenreaper Yes, that's pretty much your only option. You could use YQL, but behind the scenes, that's all it's doing.

Comment: @KevinB would it work despite the fact that the ASP is on a different domain?  I figure doing in ASP would sort of handle it via backend in a fashion similar to how you were wanting me to handle it.

Comment: Your ASP (the one that is on the same domain as your page) should make the request to the cross-domain resource.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this same error, so then I found a blog post about CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) with ASP.NET. The author also published a complete solution using ASP.NET Web.API and AJAX calls with JQuery.

Blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/07/02/cors-support-in-asp-net-web-api-rc-version.aspx

Code: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a

Comment: Thank you very much.  Ill take a look at it, when i finish my current task.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you haven't defined `username & password`

I'm not sure where you'll want these to come from. On the one hand, you might need to get these from their fields in which case you'd want something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url:  "mywebsite",
  data: {username: $('#username').val(), password:$('#password').val()},
  dataType: "jsonp",
  contentType: "application/json",
  xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(result, status, jqxhr){ alert("success"); },
  error: function(xhr, status, message){ alert(status + ": " + message); }
});
```

And this will get the value from the fields assuming they are `#username & #password`

Or, you just want to pass them as a string in which case you'd do:

```
data: {username: 'username', password:'password'},
```

And the above will just post an value `username` with the value `username` and likewise with password.

Comment: minor typo: `password:$('#password').val()` you used a # instead of a '

Comment: No public facing form.  THey are hardcoded JS variables, called username, and pw, whch are properly assigned.  ill check to confirm though

Comment: so are there any js errors then? If there are pop them up for us :)

Comment: No errors in the console.  The only queues i currently have is that error is saying **parseerror: Error: jQuery.... was not called**

Comment: ok, ignore my answer then ;) Well, can you put your entire js script up on  say jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Everything i have actually is all i really have.  The only difference is the website is different and the fact that i didnt type out the definition of username and password variables.  It pretty much is a simple anchor tag with a click event, which will call this and then alert a success (eventually printing the resulting content instead of an alert statement).

Comment: odd indeed, test out some other jquery code. Thats where i'd go with it.